# Why do my integers add like strings

Tags: javascript, html, string, integer

I am trying to create a program that creates the equations for an ellipse when given certain values. When i try to add two variables the integers add like strings. EX. -4 + 4 should equal 0 but it ends up equaling -44

```js
var vertexY = 0
var vertex2Y = 0
function solveEllipse(){
    vertexY = document.getElementById("ellipseVertexYInput").value
    vertex2Y = document.getElementById("ellipseVertexY2Input").value
    centerY = (vertexY + vertex2Y)
    console.log(centerY)
}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="forms" id="ellipseVertexDiv">
    Vertex
    <br/>
    Y    
    <input type="text" name="vertexY" class="ellipseVariableInput" id="ellipseVertexYInput">
</form>
<form method="post" class="forms" id="ellipseVertex2Div">
    Vertex 2
    <br/>
    Y    
    <input type="text" name="vertexY2" class="ellipseVariableInput" id="ellipseVertexY2Input">
    <input type="button" name="submitButton" value="Submit" class="forms submitButton" id="ellipseSubmit" onclick="solveEllipse()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `document.getElementById("ellipseVertexYInput").value` returns a string.

You could convert it to an integer using `+`: `+vertexY`

```js
var vertexY = 0
var vertex2Y = 0
function solveEllipse(){
    vertexY = document.getElementById("ellipseVertexYInput").value;
    vertex2Y = document.getElementById("ellipseVertexY2Input").value;
    centerY = +vertexY + +vertex2Y;
    console.log(centerY);
}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="forms" id="ellipseVertexDiv">
Vertex
<br />
Y    
<input type="text" name="vertexY" class="ellipseVariableInput" id="ellipseVertexYInput">
</form>
<form method="post" class="forms" id="ellipseVertex2Div">
Vertex 2
<br/>
Y    
<input type="text" name="vertexY2" class="ellipseVariableInput" id="ellipseVertexY2Input">
<input type="button" name="submitButton" value="Submit" class="forms submitButton" id="ellipseSubmit" onclick="solveEllipse()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because they are strings! The `value` property of an `input` tag will always be a string. If you want to convert the values to their numerical versions, you can use `var numberValue = Number(stringValue)`

Answer (score 1):

That's because input values are treated as strings and therefore you are concatenating strings. Try parseInt'ing them before you do your calculations.

```js
function solveEllipse(){
var vertexY = parseInt(document.getElementById("ellipseVertexYInput").value, 10);
var vertex2Y = parseInt(document.getElementById("ellipseVertexY2Input").value, 10);
centerY = (vertexY + vertex2Y)
console.log(centerY)
}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="forms" id="ellipseVertexDiv">
Vertex
<br />
Y    
<input type="text" name="vertexY" class="ellipseVariableInput" id="ellipseVertexYInput">
</form>
<form method="post" class="forms" id="ellipseVertex2Div">
Vertex 2
<br/>
Y    
<input type="text" name="vertexY2" class="ellipseVariableInput" id="ellipseVertexY2Input">
<input type="button" name="submitButton" value="Submit" class="forms submitButton" id="ellipseSubmit" onclick="solveEllipse()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that it is combining them together as if it was text. To get the numbers, you'd have to use `ParseInt(document.getElementById("ellipseVertexYInput").value)`.

In this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qb6L1yo1/1/), I fixed your code for you;

```
<form method="post" class="forms" id="ellipseVertexDiv">
  Vertex
  <br /> Y
  <input type="text" name="vertexY" class="ellipseVariableInput" id="ellipseVertexYInput">
</form>
<form method="post" class="forms" id="ellipseVertex2Div">
  Vertex 2
  <br/> Y
  <input type="text" name="vertexY2" class="ellipseVariableInput" id="ellipseVertexY2Input">
  <input type="button" name="submitButton" value="Submit" class="forms submitButton" id="ellipseSubmit" onclick="solveEllipse()">
</form>
<script>
  var vertexY = 0
  var vertex2Y = 0

  function solveEllipse() {
    vertexY = ParseInt(document.getElementById("ellipseVertexYInput").value);
    vertex2Y = ParseInt(document.getElementById("ellipseVertexY2Input").value);
    centerY = (vertexY + vertex2Y);
    console.log(centerY);
  }

</script>
```

Also, consider making your inputs number only by adding `type="number"` to them.

Comment: By not using the radix (base) you're relying on the correct autodetection of it. if the number has a leading 0 (eg 030) it would be treated as base 8 (so 030 would return 24 (base 10)